# How to escape commas in au patterns and comma separated lists?

Tags: vimrc, default-settings, pattern

How do you specify a comma literal in the kinds of comma separated lists that are ubiquitous in vim configuration?

The first example I can think of off the top of my head is in autocmds:

```
au! BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter *.java,*/src/java/* :echo "in java"
```

What if I want to match files that have a comma in their names?

```
au! BufEnter *,*.txt :echo "this file has a comma in its name"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For comma in file pattern you have to escape with `\,`.

```
au BufEnter *\,*.txt echo 'this file has a comma in its name'
```

More information with `:help file-pattern`:

```
The pattern is interpreted like mostly used in file names:
    *   matches any sequence of characters; Unusual: includes path
        separators
    ?   matches any single character
    \?  matches a '?'
    .   matches a '.'
    ~   matches a '~'
    ,   separates patterns
    \,  matches a ','
    { } like \( \) in a |pattern|
    ,   inside { }: like \| in a |pattern|
    \}  literal }
    \{  literal {
    \\\{n,m\}  like \{n,m} in a |pattern|
    \   special meaning like in a |pattern|
    [ch]    matches 'c' or 'h'
    [^ch]   match any character but 'c' and 'h'
```